# XSS javascript injection on button click

Tags: javascript, xss

I'm trying to implement an XSS attack by injecting javascript into a page that runs when a button on the target page is clicked. How can I link the script from my html file to the button on the target page? I'm tried just mimicking the button element on my html page with an onclick attribute but that doesn't work. I tried using an iframe to clickjack but I couldn't get that figured out either. This is for a school assignment so I'm not ACTUALLY hacking a legit website by the way.

Comment: Have you thought about using php?

Comment: We've been specifically told that we should be able to complete the assignment using only javascript and html.

Comment: @AlexanderBomanSkoug — To do what? An XSS attack requires crafting an HTTP request, usually one which can be expressed as a form or link in an HTML document.

Answer (score -2):

XSS is when user input is inserted directly into the DOM without escaping, allowing an attacker to craft a malicious payload that your script will run and inject into the page.

A good example would be a script that reads an error message from a query parameter, and uses `.innerHTML` to display it on the page.

```
http://insecure.website.com/example?error=Something+went+wrong
```

But when used by an attacker like so:

```
https://www.website.com/example?error=%3Cspan%20class=%22haha%22%3EPWND%3C/span%3E%3Cstyle%3E*{display:none%20!important;}.haha{display:block%20!important;}%3C/style%3E
```

Would cause a "PWND" message to appear.

This is a school assignment, so I won't give you a complete solution. But this should push you in the right direction.